# Given $f(I) \subseteq I$, prove that there exists $x \in I$ such that $f(x)=x$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Given an interval $I = [0, 1]$ and a continuous transformation $f: I \to\mathbb R$.

a) Given $f(I) \subseteq I$. Prove that there exists $x \in I$ such that $f(x)=x$.

b) Given $I \subseteq f(I)$. Prove that there exists $x \in I$ such that $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question $a)$ is well well-known.

For the second,

$ f $ is continuous at the compact $ I=[0,1] $, thus $$f(I)=[m,M]=[f(a),f(b)]$$

with $ a,b \in I$.

$$I\subset f(I)\implies $$
$$[0,1]\subset [f(a),f(b)] \implies$$
$$f(a)\le 0\;  \wedge \;  f(b)\ge 1\implies$$
$$f(a)\le 0\le a\le b\le 1\le f(b)\implies$$
$$f(a)-a\le 0 \; \wedge \; f(b)-b\ge 0$$

You can finish by IVT.